# Find maximum sized rectangle on a plane

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry

I'm given a rectangular plane with `width`, `height` and a set of rectangles defined by `left`, `top`, `width`, `height`, where left and top define left upper corner of the rectangle. My task is to find the largest rectangle that can fit among the other rectangles without overlapping.

It should be possible using Sweep line algorithm.

How can I implement that?

My thoughts so far:

1. I sort the existing rectangles so I have them starting from top to bottom.
2. I iterate the rectangles and here is what I'm not sure what to do. Do I check to the left and right of the rectangle to see if I can fit an empty rectangle?

Here's visualized an example input and desired output.
[image: result]

Comment: Thank you for the comment, @D.W. I've edited the question. Basically I got stuck on what to do when I encounter a rectangle. First I sort them to have them from top to bottom, so that our sweep line is also "going" from top to bottom. But then I'm not sure what to do next.

Comment: Thanks for the edits, looks good!  If you want to improve the chances you get an answer, here are some possible tips: 1) You can credit the source where you saw this (e.g., the textbook); or if from a homework in a course, what algorithms and concepts you have been studying over the past week or so; or if it is a practical problem, explain where you saw it. 2) If you have any running time requirements, you can list them, so we know not to waste your time with something that's too slow to be interesting to you.  3) You could list the fastest algorithm you're able to come up with.

Comment: I don't know whether this is relevant at all, but hopefully this could be something new to you https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree